# NSURLConnection is growing in instruments, is this NSURLCache?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, instruments, didreceivememorywarning, nsurlcache

So I have a memory problem with my app. The app has a MKMapView with MKOverlayRenderer which loads images on the map. Everything working ok but after 30-60 minutes the app crashes due memory.

With Instruments I found that NSURLConnection is growing and because I cannot find anything else (besides all kind of stuff I dont understand) I think thats is my problem.

Screenshot instruments after runnning for 1-2 minutes:

[image: instruments NSURLConnection]

Screenshot instruments after running for 12-13 minutes:
[image: instruments after 12-13 minutes]

Images are loaded like this in the canDrawMapRect method and saved to tmp folder (if I turn this off the NSURLConnection won't grow that high):

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[OperationQueues sharedOperationQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {


                               [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Then loaded in the drawMapRect method.

I tried fixing this with the following code:

AppDelegate:

```
int cacheSizeMemory = 4*1024*1024; // 4MB
int cacheSizeDisk = 32*1024*1024; // 32MB
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory
                                                     diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk
                                                         diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
```

ViewController:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

right after the request: [added]

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:request];
```

But as you can see in Instruments without any luck.

1. Could this be my problem?
2. Is this the NSURLCache which is growing or something else?

As requested a couple more screenshots from instruments:

[image: statistics]
[image]

Comment: Could you open the call tree by clicking the triangle next to `+[NSURLConnection _resourceLoadLoop]`?

Comment: Also, what makes you think this is related to `NSURLCache`?

Comment: In addition to the "call tree" view, can you show us the "statistics" page? I also assume that you do not have zombies turned on (because that will prevent memory from being entirely released)? My standard approach would be to focus on "statistics" page, make sure that "record reference counts" is turned on in Instruments, find objects of mine that should be released but aren't, and then drill into the reference counts details to figure out where the object's (incorrect) strong references are.

Comment: TX! Screens added. I think it's NSURLCache because I couldn't think of something else, if I comment out the NSURLConnection there the memory of NSURLConnection isnt growing. Zombies is indeed turned off, it's hard to understand the statistics page for me. Record reference counts is on.

Comment: How many network requests are made/how often is `canDrawMapRect` called? 
To really test the `NSURLCache` you should set the cacheSize to 0. (Also, in your code snippet, you only need to `setSharedURLCache`  once)

Comment: about 400 times first minute, second minute another 350. But I'm mocking my location and it is changing fast so in the real world this would be less. I set it to zero now and removed the other one. Wow wtf thinks that did it!, im testing it now a couple more times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 400 network requests in one minute seems pretty excessive. Some of those requests are probably duplicated or unnecessary. The amount of calls is obviously downloading a lot of information, and not giving the os much time to cleanup.

Second, your `NSURLCache` is actually providing **more** memory space than the default cache. I tested on my device/simulator and ios provides a default memory capacity of 512 000 bytes. You're caches are initialized with 4 194 304 bytes (and way more on disk).

I would suggest that you set your cache size smaller to see some improvement. However, investigating the amount of network requests that are made will provide longer term benefits.

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the 400 requests as well, I've found out something: Using a MKMapCamera with a tilt causes these high amounts because for each zoomlevel there is a image needed and with tilt you see the map in diff. zoomlevels. Now without 3D it's a lot less. Also I had file-caching on 1sec just to reproduce the bug as fast as possible so the 400 wasn't the actual number in production. It's now 500 requests for 5minutes while driving 100m/s (360km/h). First map zoom to the locations causes 100requests  already.